# Equality of Moment Generating Functions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, laplace-transform, fourier-transform, moment-generating-functions

Let $X,Y$ be be random variables whose moment generating functions $s\mapsto \mathbb{E}(e^{sX})$ exist and agree on either the interval $(-\delta,0]$ or on the interval $[0,\delta)$ for some $\delta > 0$.  Do $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution?

In particular, is the following argument outline valid: The Laplace transforms (with $s$ now in $\mathbb{C}$), $s\mapsto \mathbb{E}(e^{sX})$ exist on some strip $\text{Re}(s)\in (-\delta,0)$ or $\text{Re}(s)\in (0,\delta)$ and are analytic there.  Therefore, they agree on that strip, and so they agree on the boundary $\text{Re}(s)=0$, so the characteristic functions are the same.  That implies the distributions are the same.

Comment: why "analytic there"?

Comment: @mathworker21 I think you can get it from Morera's theorem.  As a reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-sided_Laplace_transform

Comment: @mathworker21 I am confused about your objection.  From the article: "Analogously, the two-sided transform converges absolutely in a strip of the form a < Re(s) < b, and possibly including the lines Re(s) = a or Re(s) = b.[2] The subset of values of s for which the Laplace transform converges absolutely is called the region of absolute convergence or the domain of absolute convergence. In the two-sided case, it is sometimes called the strip of absolute convergence. The Laplace transform is analytic in the region of absolute convergence."

Comment: Also, for $s = a+ib$, we have $|e^{-sx}f_{X}(x)| = e^{-ax}f_{X}(x)$, so saying that the transform is defined on a small interval on the real line guarantees absolute convergence on the strip in $\mathbb{C}$ corresponding to that interval?

Comment: in your question, u just said the laplace transform exists in some strip. how do you know it converges absolutely in that strip?

Comment: @mathworker21 For $z = a\in \mathbb{R}$, the Laplace transform is the Lebesgue integral of a nonnegative function.  So if it exists (is finite), then the integrand is $L^1$ (the integral converges absolutely).  Then the argument in the previous comment allows you to pass to $z =a + ib$ for any $b\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: ok, might look right

Comment: im confused. if u want to ask if an argument is right, then put the argument in your question, and ill read it

Comment: The equality of characteristic function in some neighborhood of zero does *not* imply equality of distributions. Take e.g. the chf of Polya distribution, $(1-|t|)^+$, and $1 - \arccos(\cos t)$.

Comment: @zhoraster I think we have equality of the c.h.f. everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is valid, see Theorem 2 in A note on moment generating functions by Mukherjea, Rao, and Suen.

For convenience I will quote the theorem here:

Let $0<a<b$, $M_n(t)=Ee^{tX_n}$ and $M(t)=E(e^{tX})$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} M_n(t)=M(t)$ whenever $a<t<b$. Then $F_n$, the cumulative distribution function of $X_n$, converges weakly to $F$, the cumulative distribution function of $X$.

This theorem includes your case as well, since you can just take $X_n$ to be a constant sequence.

Link to paper: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S016771520500475X